# Create static reference to Context, Use it everywhere and finally let Garbage Collected

Tags: android, memory-management, android-activity

I have a little problem about needing **Activity/Application** everywhere... 
More precisely I have classes defined like this:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

     private static Activity currentActivity;
     private static MyApp instance;

     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         instance = this;
     }

     public static void setCurrentActivity(Activity activity) {
         currentActivity = activity;
     }
}
```

And I have an Extended activity like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

       ....

       @Override
       public void onResume() {
          super.onResume();
          MyApp.setCurrentActivity(this);
       }


       ....

       @Override
       public void onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy();   
          MyApp.setCurrentActivity(null);  // for nullifying static reference

       }
 }
```

My questions are:

1. Is the above code snippet fair ?
2. Should I use `super.onDestroy();` after the `MyApp.setCurrentActivity(null);` to verify that activity is not reffered and destroyed succesfully?
3. And most important, what about **static** reference *instance*? where can I nullify it to not prevent from GC ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is the above code snippet fair ?

Nope. The biggest problem is in `MyActivity.onDestroy()`. This can be called **at any time** when the activity is no longer in use (ie: after it has **finished**). If you null out `currentActivity` in `onDestroy()` you will **not** be clearing the reference to `MyActivity`, you will be clearing the reference to whatever activity happens to be currently active at the moment. I you really want to have `currentActivity` point to the current activity, the best you can do is something like this:
       @Override
       public void onPause() {
          super.onPause();
          if (MyApp.getCurrentActivity() == this) {
              MyApp.setCurrentActivity(null);
          }
       }

Also, be aware that there is a small window between `onPause()` of an activity and `onResume()` of the next activity so that it is possible that `currentActivity` will be null during this time. Watch out for that!

> Should I use super.onDestroy(); after the
>   MyApp.setCurrentActivity(null); to verify that activity is not
>   reffered and destroyed succesfully?

See my comment above. You cannot null out this reference in `onDestroy()`.

> And most important, what about static reference instance? where can I
>   nullify it to not prevent from GC ?

You don't need to. There is only ever one instance of `MyApp` created and it lives for as long as your process exists. When Android doesn't need your process anymore it just kills the process, which will clean up everything automagically.